# How can I track the time pods are in Terminating status?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I am developing a shell script which will forcefully delete pod stuck in Terminating status(due to any reason).

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep Terminating | while read line; do 
pod_name=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}' ) name_space=$(echo $line | awk 
'{print $1}' ); kubectl delete pods $pod_name -n $name_space --grace-period=0 --force; 
done
```

But to be on safe side I want to delete pod only if its in Terminating status since last 10 minute.

How can I get this time as `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep Terminating` give AGE of pod not time of current status.

As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) pod-lifecycle status.phase can have only 5 different values and none of them is Terminating. This means that termination state in not reflected in this field and therefore filtering by the phase field will not help.

**Update1:**
After suggestions from @Vitalii following is output, These pods (statefulset) are in terminating status due to node shutdown

```
kubectl -n my_ns get pod mypod-0  -o json| jq '.status.containerStatuses[]'
{
  "containerID": "docker://bc4fdf965b19dffd5cb54dddb1931d9f522aad885d1576d03a41cd45d6d60c0d",
  "image": "mypod:1.11.0",
  "imageID": "docker://sha256:128b5cb1a95cfa001620d9e54b8cf9d0ef96b2a261cab4850accab4cfa0fe6cb",
  "lastState": {},
  "name": "mypod",
  "ready": true,
  "restartCount": 0,
  "started": true,
  "state": {
    "running": {
      "startedAt": "2021-04-21T16:42:23Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Termination date-time** is saved in Pod's property `.metadata.deletionTimestamp`:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.deletionTimestamp}"
```

or for a single pod:

```
kubectl get pod pod_name -o jsonpath="{.metadata.deletionTimestamp}"
```

Note: properties `.metadata.deletionTimestamp` and `.metadata.deletionGracePeriodSeconds` don't exist for pods in `Ready` state.

**Example:**

```
k8s-m1:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-m1   Ready      master   256d   v1.18.8   10.156.0.49   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   5.4.0-1040-gcp   docker://19.3.12
k8s-w1   NotReady   <none>   256d   v1.18.8   10.156.0.50   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   5.4.0-1040-gcp   docker://19.3.12

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                          READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
aloha-pod                                     1/1     Running       0          11d     192.168.42.159   k8s-m1   <none>           <none>
hello-pod                                     1/1     Terminating   0          11d     192.168.228.80   k8s-w1   <none>           <none>


k8s-m1:~$ kubectl get pod aloha-pod -o jsonpath="deletionTimestamp={.metadata.deletionTimestamp},  deletionGracePeriodSeconds={.metadata.deletionGracePeriodSeconds}";echo
deletionTimestamp=,  deletionGracePeriodSeconds=


k8s-m1:~$ kubectl get pod hello-pod -o jsonpath="deletionTimestamp={.metadata.deletionTimestamp},  deletionGracePeriodSeconds={.metadata.deletionGracePeriodSeconds}";echo
deletionTimestamp=2021-04-29T09:39:03Z,  deletionGracePeriodSeconds=30
```

Comment: I didn't check if the `deletionTimestamp` includes `deletionGracePeriodSeconds` interval.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `finishedAt` status in [ContainerStateTerminated v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#containerstateterminated-v1-core).

Maybe it can help you - I just dont see your output of `kubectl get pod ... -o json`.
While the pod is in the `Terminating` status - maybe you can retreive info on when the container was terminated inside the pod.

```
kubectl get pod $pod_name -n $name_space | jq '.status.containerStatuses[].lastState.terminated.finishedAt'
kubectl get pod $pod_name -n $name_space -o="jsonpath={.status.containerStatuses[].lastState.terminated.finishedAt}"
```

Comment: Its not returning anything, Infact i verified json lastState value is {}, These pods are in terminating status due to node shutdown.